# Cannot deploy contract on private network with truffle: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-contract

I'm writing a contract based on the ring mixer contract from here https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5e10d764314040b04ac7d96610b9851c8bc02815

I've tested it with ganache. Everything worked fine until I tried to deploy it on my private network. Truffle gave me the following error:

> "RingMixerV2" received a generic error from Geth that
>   can be caused by hitting revert in a contract constructor or running out of gas.
>      * Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction.
>      * Try: + using the '--dry-run' option to reproduce this failure with clearer errors.
>             + verifying that your gas is adequate for this deployment.`

I've cut down the codes as below but there's no luck. I was able to deploy it on Ropsten with Remix so I don't know what is wrong. I'm using truffle v5.0.2.

```
pragma solidity >0.4.99 <0.6.0;

contract RingMixerV2 {
    //Debug Code
    address public owner;
    constructor() public {
        //Debug Code
        owner = msg.sender;

        G1[0] = 1;
        G1[1] = 2;
        H = HashPoint(G1);
    }

    function Kill() public {
        if ( (msg.sender != owner) && (owner != address(0)) ) revert();

        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }

    //alt_bn128 constants
    uint256[2] public G1;
    uint256[2] public H;
    uint256 constant public N = 0x30644e72e131a029b85045b68181585d2833e84879b9709143e1f593f0000001;
    uint256 constant public P = 0x30644e72e131a029b85045b68181585d97816a916871ca8d3c208c16d87cfd47;

    //Used for Point Compression/Decompression
    uint256 constant public ECSignMask = 0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    uint256 constant public a = 0xc19139cb84c680a6e14116da060561765e05aa45a1c72a34f082305b61f3f52; // (p+1)/4


    //Storage of Spent Key Images
    mapping (uint256 => bool) public KeyImageUsed;

    //Storage of Token Balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public token_balance;

    //Convenience tables for looking up acceptable mix-in keys
    mapping (uint256 => uint256[]) public lookup_pubkey_by_balance;
    mapping (uint256 => bool) public lookup_pubkey_by_balance_populated;
    mapping (uint256 => uint256) public lookup_pubkey_by_balance_count;


    function EvaluateCurve(uint256 x)
        public view returns (uint256 y, bool onCurve)
    {
        uint256 y_squared = mulmod(x,x, P);
        y_squared = mulmod(y_squared, x, P);
        y_squared = addmod(y_squared, 3, P);

        uint256 p_local = P;
        uint256 a_local = a;

        assembly {
            //Get Free Memory Pointer
            let p := mload(0x40)

            //Store Data for Big Int Mod Exp Call
            mstore(p, 0x20)                 //Length of Base
            mstore(add(p, 0x20), 0x20)      //Length of Exponent
            mstore(add(p, 0x40), 0x20)      //Length of Modulus
            mstore(add(p, 0x60), y_squared) //Base
            mstore(add(p, 0x80), a_local)   //Exponent
            mstore(add(p, 0xA0), p_local)   //Modulus

            //Call Big Int Mod Exp
            let success := staticcall(sub(gas, 2000), 0x05, p, 0xC0, p, 0x20)

            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
            //switch success case 0 { revert(p, 0xC0) }
            switch success case 0 { invalid()}

            //Store Return Data
            y := mload(p)
        }

        //Check Answer
        onCurve = (y_squared == mulmod(y, y, P));
    }


    //Return H = alt_bn128 evaluated at keccak256(p)
    function HashPoint(uint256[2] memory p)
        internal view returns (uint256[2] memory h)
    {
        bool onCurve;
        h[0] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(p[0], p[1]))) % N;

        while(!onCurve) {
            (h[1], onCurve) = EvaluateCurve(h[0]);
            h[0]++;
        }
        h[0]--;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the gasLimit of your latest block `web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit` in your private chain. Eventually you have set a too small value in your genesis? There is only one location in geth's code where this error message is thrown. So I am suspecting that your cap is too low.

Comment: I believe that the gas limit is sufficient. The latest one is 24092006. In my genesis.json I set it to 0x8000000.

Comment: So I run geth with verbosity and I saw this error `invalid opcode 0xfa`. 0xfa is staticcall so any chance it was because of this line `let success := staticcall(sub(gas, 2000), 0x05, p, 0xC0, p, 0x20)
`? Actually the original code is `let success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 0x05, 0, p, 0xC0, p, 0x20)` but after upgrading truffle, it gave me error `TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.` so I changed it to staticcall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have byzantium enabled in your private network.

Check that you have `byzantiumBlock` set in the config section of your genesis.json.

`let success := staticcall(sub(gas, 2000), 0x05, p, 0xC0, p, 0x20)` is calling the precompiled contract at address 0x05, which is "Modular exponentiation (EIP 198)". This works only with byznatium enabled.